# Let $G$ be a group, $a\in G$. Show that if $|a|=n$ then $\left\langle a \right\rangle = \{e, a, a^{2}, ..., a^{n-1}\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

Suppose $|a|=n$ and $a^{k}\in \left\langle a \right\rangle$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then $\exists q,r\in \mathbb{Z}|k=nq+r, 0\le r \lt n$.
Thus, $a^{k}=a^{nq+r}=a^{nq}a^r=a^{r}$ and $a^{k} \in \{ e, a, a^{2}, ..., a^{n-1} \}$

Why does showing that $a^{k}=a^{r}$ and $a^{k}\in \left\langle a \right\rangle$ mean that $\left\langle a \right\rangle = \{e, a, a^{2}, ..., a^{n-1}\}$?

Comment: $|\langle a\rangle|=n,$ not $n-1.$ You forgot to count $e.$

Comment: Note that $0<r\leq n$ means $r\in \{1,2,\dots,n\}.$ If $r=n,$ then $a^k=a^r=e.$ Otherwise $r\in \{1,2,\dots,n-1\},$ so $a^k=a^r\in \{a^1,a^2,\dots,a^{n-1}\}.$ So we know $a^k\in\{e,a^1,a^2,\dots,a^{n-1}\}.$

Comment: $\langle a\rangle = \{a^k\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Clearly, $\{e,a,\ldots,a^{n-1}\}\subseteq \{a^k\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, so you are trying to show the converse inclusion.

Comment: But the real question is, what definition do you have for $\langle a\rangle?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I apologize the bounds were $0\le r \lt n$. The definition i have is $\{a^{n}|n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Comment: To show $A\subseteq B$, you take an arbitrary element of $A$, and who it lies in $B$. Here, $A=\langle a\rangle$, and $B=\{e=a^0,a^1,\ldots,a^{n-1}\}$. So you take an arbitrary element of $A$, which is of the form $a^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. You then show that $a^k=a^r$ for some $r$ with $0\leq r\lt n$, which means $a^r\in B$. Thus, $a^k=a^r\in B$. That proves that $A\subseteq B$, which is what you are trying to show.